# Looking up symbol documentation in Counterclockwise

Tags: clojure, counterclockwise

In Counterclockwise, if I use CTRL-Space to complete a symbol name, and there are more than one possibility, it gives me a list, and on the right and side of the list is a box with the documentation for each symbol as I scroll through the names.

Is there any way to get this documentation window without using completion, or if there is only one option for the completion? Right now I am looking up documentation by deleting enough letters for the symbol to be ambiguous, then reselecting the symbol I want, but this is pretty inefficient. Usually I just want to know what order the arguments are. I'm not a huge emacs fan, but one thing I like about slime is that I seem to remember when I used it the status bar had a little list of the arguments for whatever function I was calling.

I've googled the problem and also looked on the counterclockwise web page, but I must be using the wrong search terms because I haven't come up with anything.

-Harry

Comment: i do the same :)
seems, there is no such public (calleble by keypress) functionality, so we need to create ticket in CCW issue tracker and then hope, that it will be implemented.

Comment: I'll add it to the issues list if I get a chance; right now I'm trying out La Clojure for IDEA. (I'm just getting started in Clojure, so I'm not married to any particular IDE). It does show the documentation better, but has other quirks that are very annoying. I'll use it for a couple days and see if it's just the fact that I was already familiar with Eclipse and IDEA is new to me, or if they are really permanently annoying quirks.

Comment: Have you looked on the mailing list?  I would post this on their group list, as the maintainer and prominent supporters of CCW are quick to respond directly: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/clojuredev-users

Comment: I couldn't find a mailing list mentioned on the Counterclockwise web site, I'll have to look again. I've been to their Google Group a few times, but I've never been able to figure out how to use Google Groups effectively so it didn't really occur to me to go there for help.

Comment: The google group is the mailing list.  I would also say that you could go on the freenode IRC channel and join the #clojure channel if you're up to it.  I know the devs hang out in there, and oftentimes will spin up the #ccw channel for Counterclockwise-specific questions:  http://webchat.freenode.net

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hover the mouse over the symbol, and the documentation will popup. Or press F2 while the cursor is over the symbol.